# Как найти многоуровневый Jquery Nestable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Я нашел этот плагин https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable и использовал его в своем проекте

Но проект имеет больше уровней, чем поддержка Nestable. Самое обидное что как раз не хватает одного дополнительно уровня.

Как изменить Nestable для неограниченной вложенности?

Поиск в Google ни к чему не привел

Большая просьба не предлагать другие решения, кроме Nestable, так как у меня проект тесно завязан с ним,

Если было бы можно как-то модифицировать плагин под мультивложенность было бы просто замечательно, хотя бы еще один дополнительный уровень добавить.. Может уже есть такие модификации Nestable? Если есть пожалуйста дайте ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации есть [настройки конфигурации](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable#configuration), и там сказано про параметр `maxDepth`, который по умолчанию равен 5, но его легко можно поменять на любое нужное Вам значение:

```
$('.my-lists').nestable({
    maxDepth: 7
});
```

Больше читайте документацию, чаще всего нужный Вам функционал уже давно был нужен кому-то другому, и решение существует коробки.

Comment: спасибо Вам, очень помогли!